# Реализация condition variables

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Подскажите правильную реализацию condition variables. Реализовал на `WaitForMultipleObjects()` и `PulseEvent()` , и получил баг, когда поток не просыпался, оказалось это проблема в `PulseEvent()`. Подскажите правильную реализацию в которой поток будет точно просыпаться и работать как надо.

Comment: condition variables есть в WinAPI, начиная, кажется, с Висты. Под какую версию вам надо?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163405.aspx

Comment: Под семерку, мне нужен аналог линуксовых функций.

Comment: Ну так виста младше семёрки. Пользуйтесь. Перенесу в ответ.

Comment: То есть старше, тьфу. В смысле, раз по вистой есть, то под семёркой тем более.

Comment: а `std::condition_variable` Вам чем не угодили?

Comment: @ixSci: В вопросе тэг [tag:winapi].

Comment: @ixSci, еще спроси, чем мне boost::condition_variable не угодил. ) Зачем таскать с собой лишние библиотеки, если можно реализовать самому.

Comment: @VladD, там ещё тег C++. *mikelsv*, я спросил то, что спросил. Что Вы собрались таскать ради `std::condition_variable` мне непонятно.

Comment: @ixSci: Ну, у пакета Visual Studio нет по сути компилятора C, так что...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начиная с Vista, WinAPI содержит синхронизационные примитивы наподобие [`CONDITION_VARIABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), которые делают именно то, что вам нужно.

Вот пример использования (из официальной [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
CONDITION_VARIABLE cv;
CRITICAL_SECTION lock;

InitializeConditionVariable (&cv);
InitializeCriticalSection (&lock);

...
// ожидание
EnterCriticalSection(&lock);
while (!(условие)) // защищаемся от spurious wakeup
    SleepConditionVariableCS(&cv, &lock, INFINITE);

// работать с данными можно только внутри критической секции
// и при выполнении условия
работаем_с_данными();

LeaveCriticalSection(&lock);
```